# How can I get variable name by value in array?

Tags: c#

I want to get variable name by value in array
. But I couldn't get it...

Are const variables not added to enum Fruit's list?

How can I get this?

Is it impossible because array initialized by value?

```
class Program
{
    public enum Fruit
    {
        None = 0,
        Last = 65535
    }

    public const Fruit Apple = (Fruit)1;
    public const Fruit Banana = (Fruit)2;
    public const Fruit Cherry = (Fruit)3;
    public const Fruit Durian = (Fruit)4;
    public const Fruit Elderberry = (Fruit)5;

    static Fruit[] FruitList = new Fruit[]
    {
        Apple,
        Banana,
        Cherry,
        Durian,
        Elderberry
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //// what I want
        // input1 : 4
        // output2 : Durian
        // input2 : 2
        // output2 : Banana

        //// what I tried
        Console.WriteLine((Fruit)1); // failed

        foreach (var v in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Fruit))) // failed
            Console.WriteLine(v);

        Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetName(typeof(Fruit), 2)); // failed

        Console.WriteLine(nameof(FruitList[0])); // failed. compile error.
    }
}
```

Comment: You code would be far more readable and reliable if you added the different `const` values to your `enum Fruit`. Check [fubo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67227485/2265446).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the "Banana" to the list, only the value, 2.

You can't use the nameof() on a value only on a property.

If you need to have both Fruit name, and fruit number, i would recomend you to use a Dictonary insted.

```
    static Dictionary<Int32, String> FruitList = new Dictionary<Int32, String>()
    {
        { 1, "Apple"},
        { 2, "Banana"},
        { 3, "Cherry"},
        { 4, "Durian"},
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FruitList[1]); 

        foreach (var v in FruitList)
            Console.WriteLine(v.Value);

        Console.WriteLine(FruitList[2]); 

        Console.WriteLine(FruitList[0]); 
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks @sergioliveira07!
code snippet in question is a simplified example, actual code is auto-generated code and it has large amount const enum content..

Answer (score 4):

I think you want

```
public enum Fruit
{
    None = 0,
    Apple = 1,
    Banana = 2,
    Cherry = 3,
    Durian = 4,
    Elderberry = 5,
    Last = 65535
}
```

so you can do

```
Console.WriteLine((Fruit)1);  // Apple
```

Comment: thanks to answer @fubo.. my code snippet is an example code, actually it has large const variables and it is auto-generated code, so I want to know what certain numbers mean.